# Recovery menu missing in 18.04LTS

Tags: recovery-mode, 18.10, secure-boot

I'm trying to drop a root shell for recovery, but after the reboot, **I cannot see the recovery menu** where I should select the "Drop root shell" option.

After the secure-boot selection I just prompted for desktop user login. Why? I  a remember  recovery manu in Ubuntu 17.

Answer (score 1):

Immediately after the motherboard / computer manufacturer logo splash screen appears when the computer is booting, with BIOS, quickly press and hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, which will bring up a GNU GRUB menu screen. With UEFI press (perhaps several times) the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key to get to the GNU GRUB menu screen. Sometimes the manufacturer's splash screen is a part of the Windows bootloader, so when you power up the machine it goes straight to the GNU GRUB menu screen, and then pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> is unnecessary.

You will see a GNU GRUB menu screen that looks like this. Select **Advanced options for Ubuntu** and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

A new purple screen will appear showing a list of kernels, which includes options of booting the kernels normally or in recovery mode.

[image]

Use the ↑ and ↓ keys to select which entry is highlighted. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to boot the selected OS and kernel combination with a choice of either not in recovery mode or in recovery mode options.

[image]

From the Recovery Menu use the arrow keys to select *root* (the second entry from the bottom in the Recovery Menu) and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

(Optional): Using the arrow keys scroll down to *network* (the third entry from the bottom in the Recovery Menu) and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: That's what I expected, but the recovery menu doesn't appear! It just goes straight on to the desktop login.

Comment: If your computer has a discrete GPU take a look at this page for temporarily enabling the [nomodeset](https://askubuntu.com/tags/nomodeset/info) kernel boot option.

Comment: @karel I'm also seeing no recovery menu. How and why?

Comment: @Duos To get the Grub menu options to show, rey holding the right Shift key instead of the left Shift key.

Comment: I am also not able to see recovery menu. Please help me if anyone know what's going on.

Comment: @Kinjal The key required to access the GNU GRUB menu screen varies according to the model of the motherboard and its firmware. Also sometimes it's necessary to hold down the key instead of just pressing it.

Comment: I am able to access GRUB menu but after selecting the ubuntu os with recovery mode, i am not able to see recovery option menu (resume, clean, dpkg, etc. this menu). @karel

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 20.04 desktop, to get the Grub menu options to show, you have to hold the right SHIFT key not the left SHIFT key.