# Stuck in tty1, unable to log in (18.04 MATE)

Tags: 18.04, login, password, mate, tty

I'm stuck in the black tty1 login screen.

I think I know why. I use MATE but wanted to try cinnamon, installed it, wasn't satisfied so I removed it again via

```
sudo apt remove cinnamon-desktop-environment lightdm
```

I guess I shouldn't have included *light dm*. I just replaced *install* with *remove* in the code I used to install cinnamon and didn't think it through.

The issue is that in tty1 I can't get past the login because I am not given enough time to put in my password correctly. I put my username and then it almost immediately jumps to "login incorrect" after I hit enter and try to actually put in my password.

I have already tried  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> all the way through <kbd>F7</kbd>, but no success.

I have also tried booting with a different kernel version from the advanced options. I only have 4.15.0-45 and 4.15.0-44 available and neither worked.

Edit: this keeps getting marked as a duplicate of this post:
[TTY doesn't wait for password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1113704/tty-doesnt-wait-for-password)
But like I've stated above, I have already tried using a different kernel from the advanced options menu to no avail.
The other answer requires command lines, but how can I type those before being able to log in?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recovery menu missing in 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1091625/)