# Ubuntu 18.04.2 stucks at purple screen after install

Tags: boot, 18.04

I am very new to linux and tried to install Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS on my laptop Lenovo g405s. it had windows 7 previously. i installed ubuntu via an USB and succeed, after that it told me to remove the usb and press enter, after which i welcomed at blank purple screen. im not sure what caused this and tried several fixs i found online and all failed.

Things i've tried :

- replaced quiet splash with nomodeset -> fail
- replaced quiet splash with radeon.modeset=0 -> fail
- replaced $linux_gfx_mode with nomodeset -> fail

do i need older version of ubuntu or something else is wrong ?

Comment: Hello and welcome to askubuntu. To begin to get to grips with what the problem might be - search for instructions (on askubuntu) on how to get the computer into recovery mode. When you have that up type `dmesg | less` at the command (=shell, bash) prompt. With the text up on the screen hit `>`  to scroll down to the end of the text (hit `h` to get help on all available options) - and look for errors. You might also need to to scroll back upwards, or use less:s search function.

Comment: i cant even get into the recovery mode, it stucks as well with same purple blank screen

Comment: Read https://askubuntu.com/a/1091627/289138  - if you can make changes involving "nomodeset" then you REALLY have just to select and press enter on the top one of "... (recovery mode)" if there are more than one instead of anything else. In the recovery menu: select "fsck", "network" and then "root" options - in that order. (In 16.04 You will have to press enter one extra time to actually get the bash prompt with root access - dunno how it is in 18.04)

Comment: If the descriptionm behind the link doesn't happen for you, then I recommend to look over whether you used UEFI or Legacy boot mode - and match that with how you install Ubuntu.