# How do I get into a terminal before boot where the hard drives are unmounted?

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, hard-drive

So, I really need to use fsck on my drives, but I can't find a way because the drives need to be unmounted [aside from USB/cd which isn't available to me rn] but I remember once I got into a terminal where I could do fsck, anyone have any idea what it was?

Comment: you don't need to get to terminal before boot to unmount a drive you can use the unmount command so for example "sudo umount /dev/hda1" where hda1 is the drive name also you can open term with ctrl+alt+t. also if you want to check your disk health you can follow this (https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/disk-check.html.en)

Comment: it says target is busy

Comment: Think the recovery menu would be what you want, instead of regular boot.

Comment: even recovery mode doesn't work, still says target is busy

Comment: Are you using the second menu or booting to earlier kernel?  Recovery should have secondary menu without kernels.

Comment: just a note you cannot unmount a drive with root file system (the disk your os is running on) here is a fsck how to (https://phoenixnap.com/kb/fsck-command-linux) also if you want to make sure your disk is healthy check the smart data and self checks in the disk utility

Comment: This link will show to get to advance options for recovery.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1091625/recovery-menu-missing-in-18-04lts

Comment: I know how to do this and I already did it, but it just won't let me do fsck

Comment: just a thought you could run fsck on your os disk from a live usb session as your OS disk will not be in use then

Comment: i mentionned that in the original post, don't have access to that rn and probably won't for a while for some reasons, just looking for another way i could do it

Comment: Any Ubuntu 18.04 or greater requires the use of a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB to be able to run `fsck`... unless you have a bootable Ubuntu on a **different** HDD on the same system.